# Image not displaying in horizontal

Tags: php, css

I want the image to automatically be in horizontal, Should I put another div? because the picture will be save automatically by their position

And here's my CSS:

```
.row{
    display: block;
    height:auto;
    width:auto;
}

.box_img2{
    width: 20px;
    padding : 5px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    background-color:white;
    height:30px;
    float:center;
}
```

And here's my PHP:

```
<?php
                                include('../connection/connect.php');
                                $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM candposition ORDER BY posid ASC");
                                $result->bindParam(':userid', $res);
                                $result->execute();
                                for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
                                $dsds=$row['posid'];


                                $resulta = $db->prepare("SELECT sum(votes) FROM candidates WHERE posid= :a");
                                $resulta->bindParam(':a', $dsds);
                                $resulta->execute();
                                for($i=0; $rowa = $resulta->fetch(); $i++){
                                $dsada=$rowa['sum(votes)'];
                                }
                                echo '<div style="margin-top: 18px;">';
                                echo '<strong>'.$row['pos_name'].'&nbsp;'.'</strong><br>';

                                $results = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM candidates,student WHERE candidates.idno=student.idno AND posid= :a ORDER BY votes DESC");

                                $results->bindParam(':a', $dsds);
                                $results->execute();
                                    for($i=0; $rows = $results->fetch(); $i++){

                                        if($dsds=='Commissoner'){
                                            echo $rows['prog_id'].$rows['prog_id'].'&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$rows['prog_name'].'&nbsp;&nbsp;=&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$rows['votes'];

                                        }else {
                                            echo "<div class='row'><div class='box_img2'><br>";
                                            echo '<img src="savephp/images/'.$rows['image'].'" width="60" height="70px" />'.'&nbsp;'.$rows['lastname'].',&nbsp;'.$rows['firstname'].'<br>'.'&nbsp;=&nbsp;'.$rows['votes'];
                                            echo '</div>';
                                        }
                                        echo '</div>'.'</div>';
                                            $sdsd=$dsada    
                                        ?>
                                    <br><br><br><br><br>

                                    <img src="../img/percent.gif"width='<?php echo(100*round($rows['votes']/($sdsd),2)); ?>'height='10'>
                                <?php 


        if ($rows['votes']==0){
                            echo "<br>";}
                            else {
                            echo(100*round($rows['votes']/($sdsd),2)); ?>%<br>
                    <?php
                        }
                        echo '</div>';
                    }

                    ?>  
                    <?php
            }
            ?>
```

Here's the image:
[I want to be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dCPE.png)

Comment: "display in horizontal" what?  You mean you want multiple images to align horizontally?  Your language isn't specific enough. Show generated HTML and CSS, preferrably in something like http://fiddlesalad.com/html/.  You need to be more clear about what you are trying to do and what it's doing wrong. If it's hard to explain make a the fiddle to show what you've accomplished and use a picture to show how you want it to look.  Then, we know exactly how to modify your fiddle to get the appearance you need.

Comment: I want that It will be align in the same row

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.box_img2{
width: 20px;
padding : 5px;
background-color:white;
height:30px;
position: fixed; /* or absolute */
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-top: -15px;
margin-left: -10px;
}
```

Comment: Then explain. There are three pictures. You want all of them to be in the exact middle?

Comment: I've just edited my image on how to be my css going like that?

Answer (score 0):

Try going down this path, and looking at things like Boostrap's methods to do thumbnail grids, etc., may help you a lot.

Note, the img CSS is more of an either/or thing...one centers, the other will make it fill the 33% of its container.

```
<style type='text/css'>
    .row:before, .row:after { clear:both; }

    .img-container {
        float:left;
        width:33%;
        text-align:center;
    }
    .img-container img { /* if you want it centered */
        display:block; margin:0 auto;
    }
</style>
<div class='row'>
    <?php for($i=0; $rows = $results->fetch(); $i++) { ?>
        <div class='img-container'>
            <img src="savephp/images/<?php echo $rows['image'] ?>" width="60" height="70px" />
            &nbsp;<?php echo $rows['lastname'] ?>, <?php echo $rows['firstname'] ?><br />
            &nbsp;=<?php echo $rows['votes'] ?>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

**UPDATE** I've updated the code above to give a general idea of putting the images into the page.  You can build out the rest of the HTML and conditions as needed.  The important thing to note is that if you want 3 images across horizontally, make the width of the `.img-container` 33%.  If you only want 2 horizontally, make the width of the `.img-container` 50%.  They will automatically wrap to the next row.  Your code was creating a new `<div class="row">` for every single entry, which would put each new entry onto its own line rather than having them layout horizontally.

If you hit points where you want a 100% row, you can just give that a different class with `width:100%` and it will put itself on its own row.

Again, if you lookup how grids work with Bootstrap 3, it will help you get almost any alignment that you want, and I highly recommend using something like that to get going, and then once you're good at creating layouts...then figure out "how" they do it.

Comment: I have my php in where my div was placed

Comment: There will a message in the part of the <?php for($i=0; $rows = $results->fetch(); $i++) { ?> that will say Array to string conversion in and Undefined property: PDOStatement::$fetch

Comment: @CamilleFabreValerio, If you need help debugging the PHP, might need another post.  My only intention in the above code was to give you an example of how to make things align in the same row, horizontally, with CSS...not create working PHP code.

Comment: okey, sir tnx thank you for helping me and b-lated merry christmas :)